# Is it possible to make a value unique across more than 1 column in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite3, it's possible to add a column to a UNIQUE index, which makes it impossible to add the same value to that column more then once. It's also possible to add multiple columns to a UNIQUE index, making it impossible to add the same combination of values to those columns more than once.

However, is it possible to add two or more columns to the same **single-column** UNIQUE index? Say you have two columns "A" and "B". I want to set up a UNIQUE index such that if you add the value 5 to column A, then you can't put that value in either column "A" or "B" again. Basically, column "A" and "B" are sharing the same UNIQUE index.

---

#### Why?

I am modelling point-to-point links where *each point can only be part of one link*.

Here's a minimal example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE points (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    x INTEGER NOT NULL,
    y INTEGER NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE links (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    point_a INTEGER,
    point_b INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (point_a) REFERENCES points(id)
    FOREIGN KEY (point_b) REFERENCES points(id)
)
```

Given this example, how do I make it impossible for a point to be referenced more than once in the links table?

If there's a link that references point #1 as "point a", then point #1 **must not** be allowed to be referenced as "point a" or "point b" in any other link.

Basically what I need is to add both `point_a` and `point_b` to the **same** UNIQUE index. Is there any syntax in SQLite3 to achieve that?

---

If you can think of another table layout that can more easily solve this problem, I would love to hear it. Any alternative layout I can think of has other problems that I don't think SQLite3 can solve.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that doesn't use UNIQUE indexes. Using a "trigger", it's possible to make queries fail based on the result of subqueries.

This trigger does what I want:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER one_link_per_point
BEFORE INSERT ON links
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "Point already exists in a link")
    FROM links
    WHERE point_a = NEW.point_a
       OR point_a = NEW.point_b
       OR point_b = NEW.point_a
       OR point_b = NEW.point_b;
END
```

In short: Any time a new link is added, this trigger checks if either point A or point B already exists as point A or point B in any other link. If so, the insert query fails with an integrity error.